# How to center/add margins to bootstraps grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I got a PSD design where the grid looks like this -
[Grid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BryvW.png) the image only shows parts of the PSD because I dont own the rights to publish it in public. But as you can see the grid (blue stripes) does not go from side to side as the boostrap-grid. It starts 120px in and finish 120px before the screen (talking about the total 12 columns, not each column)

I am using bootstrap while coding up this PSD, and bootstraps grid goes from one side to the other.

My question: How can I change the bootstrap-grid (center it/add margins) so it looks the same as the grid in the psd i.e starts 120px in on the screen and finish 120px before the screen ends?

I dont need to have any content outside the grid as it is in the PSD. So I would need to rows to go from side to side but the columns to start a bit in, and finish a bit before the screen does. I can not use the bootstrap container instead of container-fluid since it will also take the rows. I can also not use offset since I then will "lose" some of the columns and no longer have 12-column available per row.

My HTML file contains of a standard fluid grid

```
<div class="container-fluid>
    <div class="row">
    <!-- A few columns in different sizes -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <!-- A few columns in different sizes -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <!-- A few columns in different sizes -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post your html

Comment: Is each of the 12 blue stripes supposed to be one of the grid items?

Comment: You can't really just add margins to the Bootstrap grid because it will break responsiveness. There already is a "gutter" of 30 px between each Bootstrap columns that's created with padding.

Comment: 4castle, what does my html have to do with this?

Comment: Skelly, Im not talking about the margin for each grid. Im talking about the ones out on the left and right side (before the first grid, and after the last). I cant use a container, since they also take the rows.

Comment: Why can't you use a container? I think @4castle means show us what you've tried so we don't have to make guesses and do all of the work for you.

Comment: Skelly, the container will also take the rows. In my case the rows should go from side to side of the screen, but the columns should start 120px in on the the screen and finish 120px before the screen. Now I am talking about the bootstrap container, I could add my own container for every row, but there must be a easier way? Do I make sense?

Comment: Do you mean for the backgound image? Are you going to have content outside the grid columns? Please update the question to clarify these things. It looks right now like there is simply a background image outside the columns and 1 row.

Comment: 4castle and Skelly. My html got nothing special. It is just a container-fluid containing a couple of row and each row has some colums. The rows goes from side to side of the screen and so does the grid. I would need the rows to go from side to side, but not the columns. Its just the "bootstap standard grid" so I did not feel it was necesary to post it?

Comment: Okay, I will update the post in 1 moment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your css

```
.row{padding: 0 120px;}
```

Comment: You can reduce that by 15 to compensate for the padding already on the columns, if that's what you need. I'm not sure how you need your layout to flow.

Comment: This works but caveat it should only be used for outer rows:
`.container-fluid>.row {padding: 0 120px;}`. Also it creates a huge outside spacing on mobile screens which isn't ideal for responsiveness. http://codeply.com/view/ynHJCDDqUd?viewport=xs

Comment: Assuming there is no other container fluids added to the code (not sure why you would, but hey, I don't presume to know what he plans with the code)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i totally understand your question, but you can try the following:

- Add a container ([Bootstrap container](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#quick-start-example))
- Add margin with css: `.col-sm-4 {margin:Your margin here;}`

Comment: See comments above :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what other content will be inside the rows? If the columns don't need to go from side to side, why not just use Bootstrap `.container`? You can still have full width content outside of the `container`..

http://codeply.com/go/HwIDGQpdbO